# Как сделать чтобы не разъезжались div'ы при масштабировании в браузере?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Я начинающий в html и css. Сделал два блока на сайте- шапку и сайдбар. разместил их, но при увеличении или уменьшении масштаба они разъезжаються. Буду очень благодарен за помощь, как сделать чтобы такого не происходило?

PS: К сожалению не могу добавить скриншоты так как это мой первый вопрос.

Comment: Куда они у вас разъезжаются то?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: При увеличении масштаба- к центру страницы, а при уменьшении- в стороны

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аккуратнее надо обращаться с размерами.

Скорее всего, магические комбинации типа `margin: 10px` с `width: 96%` дают приемлемые результаты только при определённых диапазонах ширины экрана.

Любимый многими идиотский способ борьбы с пробелами между `inline-block`ами может приводить к тому же эффекту. Надо честно удалять пробелы из разметки, а не городить костыли. Кстати, особый случай inline-блоков - пробел между псевдоэлементом и элементом при вертикальном центрировании. Сам наступил на грабли, когда перенос зависел от текста во вложенном блоке.